# How to format API response data using js map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "result": [{
        "name": "a",
        "value": 20,
        "max": 100,
        "sale_value": [{
            "no": 1,
            "name": "aaaaa",
            "price": 200
        }, {
            "no": 2,
            "name": "bbbb",
            "price": 300
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "b",
        "value": 10,
        "max": 100,
        "sale_value": [{
            "no": 1,
            "name": "ccccc",
            "price": 200
        }, {
            "no": 2,
            "name": "dddd",
            "price": 300
        }]
    }]
}
```

which I am getting in an API response and I could just map:

```
data: [
  {
    name:'a', 
    value: 20, 
    max: 100
  }
]
```

How to map `sale_value` too?

```
[
  {
    name: 'a',
    value: 20,
    max: 100,
    sale_value: [{ no: 1, name: 'aaaaa', price: 200 }],
  },
]
```

This my code:

```
axios.all([axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:3000/test")]).then(
  axios.spread(resSale => {
    this.sales = resSale.data.result.map((data, i) => {
      return {
        name: data.name,
        value: data.value,
        max: data.max,
        sale_value: [
          {
            no: data.sale_value[i].no,
            name: data.sale_value[i].name,
            price: data.sale_value[i].price
          }
        ]
      };
    });
    console.log(this.sales);
  })
);
```

Comment: You can just call the map method on sale_value inside the map function called on result. This seems like a pretty contrived example though, it would be easier to help you if you provided more context on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Josh if i can get it i will show it in website

Comment: In your example you are not manipulating the data in any way, so there is no indication if/why you need to map. You could achieve the same result with `this.sales = resSale.data.result`

Comment: @Josh i get `this.$route.params.name`  and i check if `this.$route.params.name ===this.sales.name` i will map and get value sales name = params.name
sorry if you can't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `map` on `sale_value` too as it is also an array which you want to include in your **formatted data**. Also, it doesn't seem important to do such formatting of data as you are not making any change in its property or key:

```js
const DATA = {
    result: [
      {
        name: 'a',
        value: 20,
        max: 100,
        sale_value: [
          {
            no: 1,
            name: 'aaaaa',
            price: 200,
          },
          {
            no: 2,
            name: 'bbbb',
            price: 300,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'b',
        value: 10,
        max: 100,
        sale_value: [
          {
            no: 1,
            name: 'ccccc',
            price: 200,
          },
          {
            no: 2,
            name: 'dddd',
            price: 300,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }

const data = DATA.result.map((data, i) => {
    return {
      name: data.name,
      value: data.value,
      max: data.max,
      sale_value: data.sale_value.map(saleItem => {
        return {
          no: saleItem.no,
          name: saleItem.name,
          price: saleItem.price,
        }
      }),
    }
  })
  
  console.log(data)
```

Comment: thank you so much,
i need to map it cuz if i get this.$route.params.name and i check if this.$route.params.name ===this.sales.name i will map and get value sales name = params.name sorry if you can't understand

Comment: `axios.all([axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/test')]).then(axios.spread((resSale) => { 
this.sales = resSale.data.result 
for (let i = 0; i < this.sales.length; i++) { 
if (this.$route.params.name === this.sales[i].name) { 
this.saler = [{ 
name: this.sales[i].name, 
value: this.sales[i].value, 
max: this.sales[i].max, 
sale_value: this.sales[i].sale_value.map((saleItem) => { 
return { 
no: saleItem.no, 
name: saleItem.name, 
price: saleItem.price 
}
})
}] 
}
 }`

Comment: I understand it. You are filtering based on `name`. I hope I helped you solve your problem. If not, do let me know :)

Comment: thank you so much you can help me for my problem